# C# DATAGRIDVIEW select rows and display selected rows

Tags: c#, select, datagridview

My datagrid view is populated with multiple rows of data, I want to be able to select multiple rows in my datagridview and then update the datagridview to only display the selected rows but i am getting errors

```
  public void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


       List<DataGridViewRow> rowCollection = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
       {
           rowCollection.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index]);
       }

       //dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();




  data.Tables[0].Clear();


      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rowCollection)
        {
           DataRow r = data.Tables[table].NewRow();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
          //write the data in the DataRow and then add the datarow in your datatable
          data.Tables[table].Rows.Add(r);


      }
        CreateGraph(zedGraphControl1);





    }
```

When i select the rows and click the update button i am getting the error 
"Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

- row {DataGridViewRow { Index=-1 }}  System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow

I have tried looking at the exception help for this but cannot make sense of it 
Thanks for your help

Comment: If the DGV is data-bound, you can set `DataSource = null` to unbind it. Try that when you clear the table.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that  *The `SelectionMode` property must be set to `FullRowSelect` or `RowHeaderSelect` for the `SelectedRows` property to be populated with selected rows.*

Comment: @steve I have tried using that method but it deletes all values in the datagrid view including the column names

Comment: @FlipperFlapper you should build new `DataTable` from selected rows and set `DataGridView.DataSource` by the new `DataTable`

Comment: @agent5566 how would i do that? Ive gone cross eyed from looking at this screen for too long my brain is fried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly the datagridview must not be data bound in order to manipulate the rows.

I believe that I solved this problem a couple months back but I can't get access to my projects right now.

I think you can do it by finding and removing the rows from the data source and then refresh the datagridview

(personal advice: take a short break 10-15 mins and go back at it with a clearer mind)

Comment: Yeh you were right about the break, i have seen stuff that i skimmed over before